# Can I use a Verizon iPad 3rd Generation WiFi Only?

Tags: ipad

I am considering purchasing a used iPad 3rd generation 8.9 size.  This iPad is advertised as a used 64gb Verizon iPad.  I only want to use the iPad on wifi and do not want to connect to Verizon or AT&T.  Can I do this or do I have to go through Verizon to get it to work. I have never had an iPad and I am 67 years of age so I am not familiar with what I need to look for or be careful about in buying a used iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to use the iPad without a Verizon SIM card through your WiFi network. However, it appears that there is a problem where the iPad [keeps notifying you that there is no SIM card](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6548387?start=30&tstart=0).

I would advise getting one without cellular data as you don't plan on using it anyway. Those iPads are probably cheaper and will not have the previously described problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it without activating the cellular radio.